# Error of MONGODBDriver2.4.4.0

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have facing this issues for quite sometimes, hope that got someone can save me, thx.

```
C# : MongoDBDriver 2.4.4.0
.NET Framework 4.5
Windows Console
C# Code
var cli = new MongoClient("server");
var dbObj = cli.GetDatabase("col");
var dbColObj = dbObj.GetCollection<MyColModel>("data");
dbColObj.Find(o=>o.Name == "OK").ToList();//
```

When I does this 10 times, it will success 2 times and another 8 times return the error below:

```
Exception : Unable to translate bytes [D3] at index -1 from specified code page to Unicode.
   System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Throw(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index) +5477885
   System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index) +9
   System.Text.DecoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Byte[] bytes, Byte* pBytes) +41
   System.Text.UTF8Encoding.FallbackInvalidByteSequence(Byte* pSrc, Int32 ch, DecoderFallbackBuffer fallback) +45
   System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetCharCount(Byte* bytes, Int32 count, DecoderNLS baseDecoder) +14317552
   System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetString(Byte[] bytes, Int32 index, Int32 count) +147
   MongoDB.Bson.IO.ByteBufferStream.ReadString(UTF8Encoding encoding) +301
   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonStringSerializer.DeserializeValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) +24
   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonValueSerializerBase`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) +117
   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize(IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context) +111
   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonValueSerializer.DeserializeValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) +767
   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonValueSerializerBase`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) +117
   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonDocumentSerializer.DeserializeValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) +251
   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonValueSerializerBase`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) +117
   MongoDB.Bson.RawBsonDocument.Materialize(BsonBinaryReaderSettings binaryReaderSettings) +236
   MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply) +541
   MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.Execute(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +296
   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerChannel.ExecuteProtocol(IWireProtocol`1 protocol, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +183
   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.CommandOperationBase`1.ExecuteProtocol(IChannelHandle channel, ServerDescription serverDescription, ReadPreference readPreference, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +385
```

Comment: is it possible you have more versions of driver in solution?

Comment: The latest Driver got only a version I think?